# Inner regularity on the pre-image measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous function and $\mu$ an inner regular measure on $\mathscr{B}(X)$. Show that the image measure $\mu f^{-1}$ is inner regular.

I have to show that for $U\in Y$ an open set:

$$\mu f^{-1}(U)=\sup \{ \mu f^{-1}(K):K\subset U \text{   and $K$ is compact}\}$$

First, since $K\subset U$, we have that $\mu f^{-1}(U)\geq \sup\{ \mu f^{-1}(K):K\subset U \text{   and $K$ is compact}\}$ (I am not fully sure of that because of transformations done by $f$).

Then, assuming what I said was true, I need to show the opposite inequality. The problem is that $\mu f^{-1}(K)$ with $K$ compact could be an open or compact set. If it is a compact set, then by the inner regularity of $\mu$ I have the equality. If $f^{-1}(K)$ with $K$ compact is an open set, then I don't know how to proceed, other than just applying the inner regularity of $\mu$ to the set $f^{-1}(K)$.

I am probably making it more complicated than what it is.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\epsilon >0$ the there exist a compact set $K$ such that $K \subset f^{-1}(U)$ and $\mu (f^{-1}(U)) <\mu (K) +\epsilon$. [This is by inner regularity of $\mu$]. Now $K \subseteq f^{-1}(H)$ where $H=f(K)$. Note that $H \subseteq U$. By continuity of $F$ it follows that $H$ is compact. Also $(\mu\circ f^{-1}) (U) <\epsilon +\mu (K) \leq \epsilon+(\mu\circ f^{-1}) (H)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Why do you say $K\subset f^{-1}(H)$ and why can you conclude that $H$ is compact using the continuity of $f$? I am not sure how to finish to be honest; you have a strict inequality $(\mu f^{-1}(U)<\epsilon +\mu(k)\leq \epsilon+\mu f^{-1}(H))$ but don't we need a non-strict inequality? Other than that, your reasoning completely makes sense. I am sorry if I am not seeing something obvious.

Comment: I have defined $H$ as $f(K)$. This gives $K \subset f^{-1}(H)$. $H=f(K)$ is a continuous image of a compact set and hence it is compact. RHS of the equation you are supposed to prove is $\geq \mu\circ f^{-1} (H)>\mu\circ f^{-1} (U) -\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon \to 0$ to see that RHS $\geq $ LHS.  RHS $\leq $ LHS is trivially true. @cijerez

Comment: Just to confirm, $RHS\geq LHS$ refers to $\mu\circ f^{-1}(U)\geq \mu f^{-1}(H)$ and that happens because of the $-\epsilon$? And $RHS\leq LHS$ refers to $\mu\circ f^{-1}(U)\leq \mu f^{-1}(H)$ and why is that one trivially true if $H\subset U$?

Comment: @cijerez First question: YES. Second question: any measure is monotone; the measure of  a subset is always smaller.

Comment: Exactly; so for the second question, since $H\subset U$, wouldn't that imply that $\mu f^{-1} (H) \leq \mu f^{-1}(U)$ as opposed to $\mu f^{-1}(U) \leq \mu f^{-1}(H)$?